# How to make a permanent change background-position in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know how to run the animation from point A to point B, so to speak, but do not know how to run continuously in a circle. Below is a small code prepared:

```css
.bg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.dejurka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/watercolor-patterns4.jpg) top left/30%;
  animation: bg 2s cubic-bezier(0, -0.02, 1, 0.99);
}
@keyframes bg {
  0% {
    background-position: left -100px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: left 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

help with script

Comment: If you're aware about CSS3 animation then making it infinite is a basic thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by:

> run continuously in a circle

You mean run animation in a loop, then you can add the `infinite` `animation-iteration-count` property. In the shortcode you can just add `infinite` to your `animation` property. See demo:

```css
.bg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.dejurka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/watercolor-patterns4.jpg) top left/30%;
  animation: bg 2s cubic-bezier(0, -0.02, 1, 0.99) infinite;
}
@keyframes bg {
  0% {
    background-position: left -100px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: left 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

---

## Edit: jQuery Solution

With jQuery you can use the `animate()` function to achieve the same effect.

```js
// bg animation function
function bgAnimate(speed) {
 // define bg div
  var el = $('.bg');
  // get current background y-axis position and convert to integer (strips `px`)
  var posY = parseInt(el.css("background-position-y"));
 
  // animate element
  el.animate({
   'background-position-y': posY + 100 // add 100px
  },{
    duration: speed,
    easing: 'linear',
   complete: function() {
     bgAnimate(speed); // repeat aniamtion (loop)
    }
  });
}
bgAnimate(1000); // call function
```

```css
html, body {padding: 0;margin: 0;}

.bg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://www.dejurka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/watercolor-patterns4.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: but I need a javascript,  because not all browsers support this style

Comment: If a browser supports CSS animation, it will support `animation-iteration-count` too. Unless you want a polyfill for the whole animation property (usually to work for IE9 and below) then you can use the jQuery `animate` function. See my updated answer.

Comment: This is my answer to my question: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497828/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-backround-position-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js